# validation of input mask in FromGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I got example of credit card `FormGroup`, using Angular `directive`, I created `input mask` for input `4444444444444444` became `4444 4444 4444 4444`, but the problem is I got regex validation
which do not accept `space`. this is what I had tried,

**ts.file**

```
  {
    this.creditCardForm = builder.group({
      creditCardNumber: ['', [creditCardNumberValidators]]
    });

  }   
}

function creditCardNumberValidators(c: FormControl) {
  const isVisa = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;

  return isVisa.test(c.value)
    ? null
    : {
        validateInput: {
          valid: false,
        },
      };
}



@Directive({
  selector: '[creditCardMask]',
})
export class CreditCardMaskDirective {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (trimmed.length > 16) {
      trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 16);
    }

    const numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < trimmed.length; i += 4) {
      numbers.push(trimmed.substr(i, 4));
    }

    input.value = numbers.join(' ');
  }
}
```

and this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-qz2nst?file=app/app.component.ts), based on my finding I can have 2 solutions:

- find regex that accept space
- change `creditCardNumber` value (remove space) using `.replace(/\s/g,
  '')` and `.toString()`, but the problem is i not sure how to change
  value before it populate into FormGroup for validation

need suggestion and if there are better practice to solve this, thanks

Comment: Under `creditCardNumberValidators`, changing it to `isVisa.test(c.value.replace(\/s\g, ''))` works for me. Tried with Stripe's test card 4242 4242 4242 4242.

Comment: im try, but the form still invalid, it only true when `4444 4444 4444 4`, it count space too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same regex you are using but remove spaces from card number before validating.

You can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to do that.

```
function creditCardNumberValidators(c: FormControl) {
  const isVisa = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;

  // Remove spaces.
  let cardNumber = c.value.trim().split(' ').join('');

  return isVisa.test(cardNumber)
    ? null
    : {
        validateInput: {
          valid: false,
        },
      };
}
```

[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can also be used to remove spaces.

```
let cardNumber = c.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

**Live demo on StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-12jq6d

Comment: try on your stackblitz, the form still invalid

Comment: try and error found out the form only valid when `4444 4444 4444 4`, it count space too

Comment: @hafizi - It is not counting space. You can add `console.log(cardNumber);` to see that the number doesn't have space when validating. What is the input for which you are getting invalid? Take a look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html to see valid regex for Visa cards.

Comment: forked your stackblitz, the form still invalid until it got 16 character, here i attached gif https://imgur.com/a/HiWl9SA.... your stackblitz forked..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-fee9hu?file=app/app.component.ts  @Nikhil

Comment: @hafizi - Visa Cards have 13 or 16 digits. So when number of characters are 13 or 16, the form is showing as valid. This is the expected output. What are you expecting to happen? Do you want to only validate after user submits the form?

Comment: let say I enter `4444 4444 4444 4444` , the supposed to be the form valid right ? but the form still invalid

Comment: @hafizi - It is valid and it showing as valid too. Check again.